# "It may be updated below." or "It may be updated, below."

Tags: punctuation, commas

Which is the correct way to punctuate this sentence? Is the comma necessary?

Context:

> The following is our initial estimate. It may be udpated, below.

The intent is to say that half a page from now, there may be updated text. This is not the actual context, but it is representative.

Comment: Please, please, please give context to the quotation!

Comment: 1. Check spellings: *updated*, not *udpated*. 2. In any case, "It may be updated, below." does not seem to make enough sense to the unsuspecting reader. Doesn't work.

Comment: Apparently the idea seems to be to say: "It may **have been** updated. **Check** below."

Answer (score 1):

“It may be updated, below.” seems to be a better option, I guess.

One similarity is - "I will do it, soon."

Answer (score 1):

I agree that "(see below)" is probably better, but I would not put a comma in the original as "below" directly indicates where the update will (may) appear.

Answer (score 0):

'See below', or 'please see below', often in parentheses, are commonly used to indicate what you want to convey:

“It may be updated (see below).”